# How to plot an arrow at the candle that touches ema9 with the condition that at least 5 candles before it did not touch

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I would like to make an indicator that labels all the candles that touch the exponential moving average 9 (regardless of from below or above it) as long as there at at least 5 consecutive candles before it that did not touch the ema9. It would be even better if the code only labelled the first occurrence every day and reset daily.

this is my code currently but it does not seem to work

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

//Plotting the EMA9
ema9=ta.ema(close,9)
plot(ema9)

//Count 5 consecutive candles
var startCounter = false
var counter = 0

ema9touch = ema9<=high and ema9>=low

startCounter := ema9touch ? true : startCounter
counter := startCounter ? counter + 1 : counter

if ema9touch
    startCounter := false
    counter := 0

plotshape(counter == 21 ? 1 : 0, 'Buy Label', shape.cross, location.belowbar, color.green, size = size.normal, text = 'BUY', textcolor = color.green)
plotchar(counter, 'Counter', ' ', display = display.data_window)
```